# It is possible to make 100% transparent a polygon progressively?

Tags: opengl-es

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use Blend to make a polygon transparent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588254/how-to-use-blend-to-make-a-polygon-transparent)

I need to make progressively invisible a polygon with OpenGL ES 1.1. I'm developing for Android, but i think that other platforms will do the same code with some minor changes.

How i can do that?

The polygon haves texture, is not a colores polygon.

Comment: Please stop repeatedly asking the same question.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the texture environment to `GL_MODULATE`, then progressively change the color from solid white to transparent white.

```
glTexEnv (GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
glBegin (GL_QUADS);
glColor4f (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, opacity);
glTexCoord...
glVertex...
... rest of vertices ...
glEnd ();
```

Then vary opacity over time to go from 1.0 down to 0.0. `GL_MODULATE` causes the texture to be multiplied by the color of the polygon.

Comment: my polygon doesn't have color, it haves a texture. How can i do that with a textured polygon?

Comment: i'm trying your code but isn't working, i think because my polygon is textured....

Comment: All polygons have a color - whatever the current `glColor` is. Why don't you post your code and let us see what you're trying to do, and then maybe we can see what's going wrong.